# elements are not being added to array dynamically in recursion

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter application, I have defined an array in a function (lets say function-A) and I dynamically add some values to that array inside function-A.

I call another function (lets say function-B) from function-A and this function-B recursively adds some values to original array defined inside function-A. But the problem is that when I finally print the array, it only has values added inside function-A.

So please tell why elements are not being pushed into the array inside function-B?

**Code:**

```
function A() {
    $ChnCat_tags = array();

    //some code

    $ChnCat_tags[] = array(
        'level' => $level,
        'value' => $row_vct->id_vct,
        'label' => $row_vct->displayname_vct,
        'disable' => $disb
    );

    recursion_result = function-B($ChnCat_tags);

    print_r($ChnCat_tags); //only prints values added in function-A
}


function B($ChnCat_tags) {

    //some code

    $ChnCat_tags[] = array(
        'level' => $level,
        'value' => $row_vct->id_vct,
        'label' => $row_vct->displayname_vct,
        'disable' => $disb
    );

    recursion_result = function-B($ChnCat_tags);

    return recursion_result;
}
```

Comment: and how u r using it with codeigniter? pls specify

Answer (score 0):

Hello You just need to pass your array variable as reference in function B when you called that function from function A and your work will be done.
check below code:

```
function A() {
$ChnCat_tags = array();

//some code

$ChnCat_tags[] = array(
    'level' => $level,
    'value' => $row_vct->id_vct,
    'label' => $row_vct->displayname_vct,
    'disable' => $disb
);

recursion_result = function-B(&$ChnCat_tags);

print_r($ChnCat_tags); //only prints values added in function-A
```

}

```
function B($ChnCat_tags) {

//some code

$ChnCat_tags[] = array(
    'level' => $level,
    'value' => $row_vct->id_vct,
    'label' => $row_vct->displayname_vct,
    'disable' => $disb
);

recursion_result = function-B($ChnCat_tags);

return recursion_result;
}
```